# Circumflex in a pdf bookmark using \texorpdfstring

Tags: hyperref, pdf, characters, bookmarks

In this MWE, how could you add a circumflex inside `pdfstring` argument of the `\texorpdfstring` command so it can be displayed in the pdf bookmarks?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{\texorpdfstring{Section $\mathbb{R}^k$}{Section R^k}}
Blah blah

\section{\texorpdfstring{Section $\mathbb{R}^k$ bis}{Section R\^k}}
Blah blah

\section{\texorpdfstring{Section $\mathbb{R}^k$ bis bis}{Section R\^ k}}

Blah blah

\end{document}
```

And this is what I am currently obtaining in the bookmarks:

[image: Capture]

What I would like to display in the bookmark is "Section R^k", with the circumflex (if this is possible...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the 'ASCII' circumflex provided by `textcomp`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{\texorpdfstring{Section $\mathbb{R}^k$}{Section R\textasciicircum k}}
Blah blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @cfr, it works as expected. Just for curiosity, would be possible to invoke directly the ASCII code without requiring the package?

Comment: @epsilone Well it is not really a matter of the ASCII code. Rather, it is a matter of accessing a particular character in the font under the TS1 font encoding. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font for information about ways to get a single symbol from a font. I don't, to be honest, see much point in doing so. `textcomp` is a useful package anyway (I just load it by default the same way I enable the T1 encoding and UTF8 input - it isn't worth thinking about whether I need it or not).